# Map sql view to existing entity in EF 6?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table dbo.Tasks,  class for Task, a TaskMap,  and add it to the DB context no problem.  I also have a database view dbo.vwComplexTaskQuery that returns Tasks.  How do I map this view to my task class?  I would like to be able to do:

```
List<Task> Tasks = db.vwComplexTaskQuery.ToList();
```

Without having to create a vwComplextTaskQuery class that has the same properties and same data annotations.

Simplified Task Class

```
public class Task
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Simplified Task Map Class

```
        public TaskMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.TaskId);
        this.Property(t => t.Title)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Tasks");
        this.Property(t => t.TaskId).HasColumnName("TaskId");
        this.Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("Title");

    }
```

Is this possible,  if so an example or link to documentation would be great.

Answer (score 4):

I found one solution:

```
List<Task> tasks = db.Tasks.SqlQuery("Select * from vw_AllTasks").ToList<Task>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost 4 years later... (EF6 has been out that long already? wow...)

EF does not handle VIEWs very well by default: both the EDMX ("Database first") and "Code first" reverse-engineering stuff makes some silly assumptions about views (e.g. that a View can't have the same type as an Entity, a View's Entity doesn't have relationships with other Entities, all of a View's `NOT NULL` columns must be a composite primary key, etc...

...but if you manually override whatever EF generates such that it thinks a VIEW is a table then it works perfectly correctly (navigation properties, etc). But doing this is kinda difficult and needs to be re-done whenever you update your Model from the database.

Fortunately there's a solution - if you don't mind getting your hands just a bit dirty: There's a third-party, open-source, Entity Framework model generator T4 template (no VS Extensions required: just include 3 files in your project (also available as a NuGet package) called ReversePOCO: https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator (disclaimer: I contributed some patches a few months ago specifically to support `VIEW` handling).

By default, the T4 template in ReversePOCO generates code similar to what EF6's Code First generator creates, but handling VIEWs is straightforward:

1. In your `Database.tt` file (where you configure ReversePOCO's `Settings` object) ensure that `Settings.IncludeViews = true`.
2. Look for the `Settings.ViewProcessing` callback (around like 310 in version 2.37.1).

   - Uncomment the existing code and modify it to suit your preferences. You will need to list which columns in the view are primary keys.
3. Look for the `Settings.AddForeignKeys` callback (around line 326 in version 2.37.1).

   - Uncomment the existing code and modify it to match the foreign-key relationships you'd like. This will ensure the Navigation properties are created correctly (composite foreign-keys are fully supported).